# How to call a function in python at different times?

Tags: python, function, button, beautifulsoup, pysimplegui

I need to call a certain function when the button is clicked and the code I wrote works perfectly only when the button is pressed the first time. If I press the button again It won't call the function but it prints the string I coded to print when the button is pressed.What can I use to make the function able to call multiple times? Thanks. Here is the code.  Please Help Me

```
sg.theme('DarkAmber')
layout = [  [sg.Text('URL'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Cancel'):   # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    url = values[0]
    Mainfunction()
    print('Button pressed here is the value ', values[0])
```

Comment: if you change `break` to `continue`?

Comment: break is actually when I press the cancel button. pls, understand the question when I press the button call function button. It prints the string which is needed to print(The Print String is inside the button on click statement) but it does not call the function. Anyways Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually made an simple error that would make the function work the correct way on the second time it is called. So Myfunction is like

```
var1 = 0
def Function:
    if(var1 == 0):
        //do some shit
        var1 = var1 + 1
    if(var1 == 1):
        //do some shit
        var1 = var1 + 1
```

So, I found out the Function is being called and executed but the arguments does not meet their requirements(Or some wierd shit. Am a NOOB) 
defining the variable inside the function made would do the work. Likeways, The code would be,

````
def Function:
    global var1 // If you wanna make it global
    var1 = 0
    if(var1 == 0):
        //do some shit
        var1 = var1 + 1
    if(var1 == 1):
        //do some shit
        var1 = var1 + 1  
``` Hope it Helped You
````